# Does anyone know of an online source for חידושי רב נחום?

Tags: talmud-gemara, product-recommendation, torah-study

Seeing if anyone knows somewhere online I can get ahold of the sfarim of Nochum Partzovitz on shas.‎

I think they're called חידושי רב נחום

Thanks!

Edit:‎ Ideally free,‎ but curious either way

Comment: FYI - it is חדושי רבי נחום

Comment: There is also שיעורי רבי נחום

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find the following editions of **חדושי רבי חנום** on the Otzar website.

[Bava Kammah](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=61720&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16040662222942932)

[Bava Metziah](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=194461&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16040662222942932)

[Bava Basra](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=60358&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16040662222942932)

[Gittin](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=60357&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16040662222942932)

[Yevamos](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=60354&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16040662222942932&pagenum=1)

It will allow you to have 150 pages of free access and the remaining pages will come with a charge.

---

Likewise you can access the **שיעורי רבי נחום** there as well:

[Bava Metziah & Bava Basra](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=60356&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16040662222942932&pagenum=1) (first 150 pages free)

[Yevamos & Gittin](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=60355&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16040662222942932) (first 150 pages free)

[Pesachim](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=144556&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16040662222942932&pagenum=1) (whole sefer is free)

And another version on [Nedarim - perek na'arah hamurasah](https://tablet.otzar.org/en/book/book.php?book=159890&width=-17&scroll=0&udid=16040662222942932&pagenum=1) (whole sefer is free)